# Is there a way to force the Apache Camel http4 producer to stream instead of use chunked encoding?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to call a web service that requires streaming and I'd like to use the Camel http4 endpoint, however I can't seem to get it to stop using chunked encoding. Is there a way to either force streaming or turn off chunking?

Comment: Probably not. --Lloyd Just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this may force http4 to stream your data:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
```

You can find more details on the complete example: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-http4/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpCompressionTest.java

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable stream cache. See this:
https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/stream-caching.html